# What is the most efficient way to sum integers in a range?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, sum, integer

```
for  i  in  range(0,1000000): 
   j  +=  i
```

What is the `performance issue` with this code and how can it be fixed?

My understanding is that it can lead to `IntegerOverflow` ? If not, what other issues are there and how can it be done in the most efficient way?

Edit: This is an interview question , This has a performance issue and there is a better way to do it according to the question

Comment: It seems to run fine, as well as quickly.

Comment: There's always `sum(range(0,1000000))` too.

Comment: @Johnny  This is an interview question , This has a performance issue and there is a better way to do it according to the question

Comment: @MarkMeyer This is an interview question , This has a performance issue and there is a better way to do it according to the question

Comment: @Simrankaur performance issues are relative. `sum(range(0,1000000)) ` runs in about 20ms on my laptop. Is that a performance issue? I don't know — it depends on the context. You *can* do the math, which makes things more complicated and less flexible, but simpler computationally : `((1000000-1)/2) * 1000000`

Comment: Hint: It wastes something.  What could it be?

Comment: Regarding integer overflow, ["All integers are implemented as 'long' integer objects of arbitrary size"](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#integer-objects) and thus cannot overflow.

Comment: @Paul:  Is it Space that it wastes?

Comment: What kind of space? Space, the final frontier?  Is it bigger on the inside than on the outside?

Comment: Since it is a sum of first n natural numbers this code is taking O(n) complexity which can be easily done in O(1). You can now guess how it can be done in O(1)

Comment: @EXODIA Well, yes, you could simply use n*(n+1)/2. That requires almost no memory or cpu time.... but of course that's never the answer :-)

Comment: I think the usual alternative is to use xrange (python 2) or a while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a math problem.

If you want to compute the total of positive integers ranging from `n` to `m`:

```
def sum_range(n,m):
    d = m - n
    return n * (d+1) + int(d*(d+1)/2)
```

Consider the example `sum_range(4,8)`, you can represent this as summing the x's in this:

```
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

Which can be broken down into of 4 (n) times 5 (8 - 4 + 1, i.e. the number of numbers) and the sum of the range from 0 to 4:

```
xxxx
xxxx x
xxxx xx
xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxx
```

Summing from `0` to `n` is a well known sum, which comes down to `(n * (n+1)) / 2`.

Answer (score 3):

Python ints are unbounded - they won't overflow (well, in Python 3 - in Python 2 there were both bounded and unbounded ints).

The problem with summing a range "naively" is merely time.  Your loop goes around a million times, but works fine:

```
>>> j = 0
>>> for  i  in  range(0,1000000):
...     j += i
>>> j
499999500000
```

It's very much faster to think ;-)  The sum of an arithmetic sequence is merely its average term times the number of terms.  So, for this example:

```
>>> r = range(0, 1000000)
>>> first = r[0]
>>> last= r[-1]
>>> (first + last) * len(r) // 2
499999500000
```

Now the number of operations needed is a small constant no matter what the range.

The same code works for any range.  For example,

```
>>> r = range(100000000, 19, -17)
>>> sum(r)
294117697058808
>>> first = r[0]
>>> last = r[-1]
>>> (first + last) * len(r) // 2
294117697058808
```